# C++/Cmake - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsentry

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to install sentry library in my C++ project.

[Here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/?_ga=2.209395026.1999448888.1661163526-1777496672.1660842843&_gac=1.12391878.1660842962.Cj0KCQjwxveXBhDDARIsAI0Q0x07i4flnMvjMsYhWWvWmzkeTuqwc0F-jeHzU3c7DeA6ewuFMEWC1bUaAryVEALw_wcB) is the link of their docs of how to install it.

Here is the files generated after I have build their library:

[image]

I've created a folder called `dep` in my project where I keep dependencies. And since I want to add sentry library as dependency I've created a folder inside:

[image]

And here is the contents of the sentry library CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(sentry SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(sentry PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libsentry.so )
```

Here is how I've tried to link `sentry` library to my main project:

```
target_include_directories(${AppName} PUBLIC ../../dep/sentry)

target_link_libraries(${AppName} PUBLIC
        Common
        asio
        sentry
        ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        gRPC::grpc++
        gRPC::grpc++_reflection
        )
```

When I try to build my project I get this error:

```
[ 52%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/WorldServer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsentry
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/build.make:1499: bin/WorldServer] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:632: Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:639: Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:203: WorldServer] Error 2
```

Any idea how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, definition of an IMPORT'ed library is **local** to its `CMakeLists.txt` and its descendants. You define the target `sentry` in `sentry/CMakeLists.txt`, so your main `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't see it.

Any of the following should fix the problem:

- add GLOBAL keyword for define `sentry` globally:

  ```
  add_library(sentry SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
  ```
- move definition of `sentry` target into main `CMakeLists.txt`.
- instead of `sentry/CMakeLists.txt` create any `.cmake` file and include it via `include()` command.

---

Actually, [Sentry project](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-native/tree/0.5.0) provides ready-make scripts for use the library in CMake.
Assuming under `sentry/` directory you have **complete installation** of the library, your could use `find_package` for create IMPORTED target:

```
# in main CMakeLists.txt

# Among other things, this creates sentry::sentry IMPORTED target.
find_package(sentry REQUIRED PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sentry)
...
target_link_libraries(${AppName} PUBLIC
  ...
  sentry::sentry # Use IMPORTED target for link with the library.
  ...
)
```

Comment: I've added the to the main project CMakeLists.txt this `find_package(sentry REQUIRED PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/sentry)` and to `target_link_libraries` this: `sentry::sentry` however the project can't now find sentry.h to start compiling. Any idea ?

Comment: I've copied the contents of /sentry/install to /myproject/dep/sentry and it seems it can't find sentry.h

Comment: Weird, according to [CMakeLists.txt:L332](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-native/blob/0.5.0/CMakeLists.txt#L332) `find_package(sentry)` should "attach" proper include directory to the target `sentry::sentry`. Could you build your project with additional `VERBOSE=1` and check `-I` parameters, which specify include directories?